# Extract info between two columns in array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
array (size=48)
  0 => 
    array (size=19)
      'type' => string 'house' (length=5)
      'name' => string 'House Committee on Agriculture' (length=30)
      'url' => string 'http://agriculture.house.gov/' (length=29)
      'minority_url' => string 'http://democrats.agriculture.house.gov/' (length=39)
      'thomas_id' => string 'HSAG' (length=4)
      'house_committee_id' => string 'AG' (length=2)
      'subcommittees' => string '' (length=0)
      0 => 
        array (size=4)
          'name' => string 'Conservation and Forestry' (length=25)
          'thomas_id' => string '15' (length=2)
          'address' => string '1301 LHOB; Washington, DC 20515' (length=31)
          'phone' => string '(202) 225-2171' (length=14)
      1 => 
        array (size=4)
          'name' => string 'Commodity Exchanges, Energy, and Credit' (length=39)
          'thomas_id' => string '22' (length=2)
          'address' => string '1301 LHOB; Washington, DC 20515' (length=31)
          'phone' => string '(202) 225-2171' (length=14)
      2 => 
        array (size=4)
          'name' => string 'General Farm Commodities and Risk Management' (length=44)
          'thomas_id' => string '16' (length=2)
          'address' => string '1301 LHOB; Washington, DC 20515' (length=31)
          'phone' => string '(202) 225-2171' (length=14)
      3 => 
        array (size=4)
          'name' => string 'Livestock and Foreign Agriculture' (length=33)
          'thomas_id' => string '29' (length=2)
          'address' => string '1301 LHOB; Washington, DC 20515' (length=31)
          'phone' => string '(202) 225-2171' (length=14)
      4 => 
        array (size=4)
          'name' => string 'Biotechnology, Horticulture, and Research' (length=41)
          'thomas_id' => string '14' (length=2)
          'address' => string '1301 LHOB; Washington, DC 20515' (length=31)
          'phone' => string '(202) 225-2171' (length=14)
      5 => 
        array (size=4)
          'name' => string 'Nutrition' (length=9)
          'thomas_id' => string '03' (length=2)
          'address' => string '1301 LHOB; Washington, DC 20515' (length=31)
          'phone' => string '(202) 225-2171' (length=14)
      'address' => string '1301 LHOB; Washington, DC 20515-6001' (length=36)
      'phone' => string '(202) 225-2171' (length=14)
      'rss_url' => string 'http://agriculture.house.gov/rss.xml' (length=36)
      'minority_rss_url' => string 'http://democrats.agriculture.house.gov/Rss.aspx?GroupID=1' (length=57)
      'jurisdiction' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'policy and oversight of some federal agencies, and it can recommend funding appropriations' (length=90)
          1 => string 'for various governmental agencies, programs, and activities, as defined by House' (length=80)
          2 => string 'rules.' (length=6)
      'jurisdiction_source' => string 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_Committee_on_Agriculture' (length=59)
```

There are some values I need to extract into an array, subcomittess is a string of lenght 0 but in this case have 6 blocks and each block is an array but, how can I get the info for subcomittess and jurisdiction?

I have been working on this for hours and I can't find the solution, I would appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: This question is not clear. What do you mean you want to "get the info for subcommittees and jurisdiction"? Provide an example of the thing you've tried, and how it has failed.

Comment: Do you expect `subcommittees` to be a key pointing to an array of objects? If so, this is not the case with your code. The subarray itself doesn't have a key.

Comment: Where did this array come from? If it is your code that created it, you need to look for an error there, something like `$your_array[] = $subcommittee;` instead of `$your_array['subcommittees'][] = $subcommittee;`.

Comment: The info is coming from a yaml file and I'm using spyc for work with php

Answer (score 0):

These 6 blocks are not part of subcomittess. They are values of the same array and can be accessed by their keys: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

Comment: This is true, but I suspect the problem is in the code that created the array in the first place, as described by @Don'tPanic above.